# Perceived disrespect from other team

Tags: communication, colleagues, collaboration

Where I work there are several software programming teams all focusing on different products using completely different technical stacks.  I've noticed a somewhat disturbing pattern in that I perceive a significant amount of disrespect from other teams based on, what I can only assume, is our different technology (language) that we write in.  Some quick examples of where I've seen this manifest:

- In group meetings with all teams we've had folks make degrading comments or simply say things that aren't true about what we are capable of.  (For what its worth, I don't think is particularly intentional, but just something that they say out of ignorance.)
- When these groups have to work together, I've seen people lecture my team members on basic programming techniques (implying that they believe we don't know what we are doing or are completely amateur).
- We will often be left out of important meetings or discussions around things that we care about or have knowledge on.
- We've had instances where one team is described as "Enterprise" and others are not, without any real benchmark as to what makes a team or product "Enterprise".

In general, I think my sentiment is that I feel disrespected and that my contributions are less valuable than others.

I guess the question I am asking is, how do I make these teams work better together?  How can I communicate that we are equals and that we should be treated as such?  Is this something better left to management and not something senior devs should concern themselves with?

Comment: Perhaps you're trying to avoid specific technical discussion, but is it necessary to mask... is it PHP?

Comment: No, I didn't really think its relevant to add what specific technologies, because this isn't a technical forum, but this is between Python and Java.

Answer (score 2):

This is something that has to be fixed from the top down. So management has to get involved. Bring your concerns to your boss, especially if you are not being included in meetings that concern you.